# Why doesnt fileupload control uploads multiple files with same data inside it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, file-upload, .net-4.0

I am using `FileUpload` control in ASP.NET and uploading multiple files with it, but the problem is that it uploads multiple files with same content in it, i.e. if I upload 4 images `image1.png`, `image2.png`, `image3.jpg`, `image4.gif` then it contains same pic/data inside each picture. Why?

.aspx code:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadMaps" AllowMultiple="true" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnFieldMapPath" runat="server" />
```

.cs code:

```
if (FileUploadMaps.HasFiles)
{
    foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedfile in FileUploadMaps.PostedFiles) 
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedfile.FileName);
        FileUploadMaps.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/") + fileName);

        mngUploadedMaterialMaps.InsertUploadedMaterialMaps(fileName, "", PropertyDetailsID);
    }
}
```

Comment: `FileUploadMaps.SaveAs` doesn't seem right. Wouldn't it be `uploadedfile`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the FileUpload with multiple files, you should use the [`HttpPostedFile.SaveAs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httppostedfile.saveas.aspx) method, not the control-side one, like this:

```
if (FileUploadMaps.HasFiles)
{
    foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedfile in FileUploadMaps.PostedFiles) 
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedfile.FileName);
        uploadedfile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/") + fileName);
        mngUploadedMaterialMaps.InsertUploadedMaterialMaps(fileName, "", PropertyDetailsID);
    }
}
```